# register_sidebar is called the wrong way WordPress version 4.2.0

Tags: php, wordpress

I working on an Intranet which I develop on a WordPress architecture on a IIS server (windows server), and I get this error on the top of the page:

> Notice: register_sidebar is called the wrong way. No id has been configured in the argument table of the "New" side column. "Sidebar-1" will be used by default. Manually configure id with "sidebar-1" to make this notification disappear and keep the current content of the sidebar. Please read Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 4.2.0.) In C: \ IIS \ Intranet \ wp-includes \ functions.php on line 5313

Here is the line 5313 of the functions.php files the error talk about:
[image: Here is the line 5313 of the functions.php files the error talk about]

I don't know how to solve the problem because I don't know where I can't change the sidebar ID, and there is no "register_sidebar()" function in this file

Comment: First of all: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: _“and there is no "register_sidebar()" function in this file”_ - this is only the file that creates the extended error message, it is not the place where the actual error occurred. So go figure out where in your template files/other scripts/plugins `register_sidebar` gets called.